# using lxml to find the literal text of url links

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, lxml.html

(Python 3.4.2) First off, I'm pretty new to python--more than a beginner but less than an intermediate user.

I'm trying to display the literal text of url's in a page by using lxml. I think I've ALMOST got it, but I'm missing something. I can get the actual url links, but not their titles.

Example--from this,

```
<a class="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2" dir="ltr" aria-describedby="description-id-588180" data-sessionlink="ei=6t2FVJLtEsOWrAbQ24HYAg&amp;ved=CAcQvxs&amp;feature=c4-videos-u" href="/watch?v=I2AcJG4112A&amp;list=UUrtZO4nmCBN4C9ySmi013oA">Zombie on Omegle!</a>
```

I want to get this:

```
'Zombie on Omegle!'
```

(I'll make that html tag a little more readable for you guys)

```
<a class="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2"
   dir="ltr" aria-describedby="description-id-588180"
   data-sessionlink="ei=6t2FVJLtEsOWrAbQ24HYAg&amp;ved=CAcQvxs&amp;feature=c4-videos-u"
   href="/watch?v=I2AcJG4112A&amp;list=UUrtZO4nmCBN4C9ySmi013oA">
       Zombie on Omegle!
</a>
```

I'm trying to do this from a YouTube page, and one of the problems is that YouTube doesn't specify a tag or an attribute for the titles of its links, if that makes sense.

Here's what I've tried:

```
import lxml.html
from lxml import etree
import urllib

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/user/makemebad35/videos'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
content = response.read()
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(content)
tree = lxml.etree.HTML(content)
parser = etree.HTMLParser()

href_list = tree.xpath('//a/@href')
#Perfect. List of all url's under the 'href' attribute.
href_res = [lxml.etree.tostring(href) for href in href_list]
#^TypeError: Type 'lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult' cannot be serialized.

#So I tried extracting the 'a' tag without the attribute 'href'.
a_list = tree.xpath('//a')
a_res = [lxml.etree.tostring(clas) for clas in a_list]
#^This works.

links_fail = lxml.html.find_rel_links(doc,'href')
#^I named it 'links_fail because it doesn't work: the list is empty on output.
#   But the 'links_success' list below works.
urls = doc.xpath('//a/@href')
links_success = [link for link in urls if link.startswith('/watch')]
links_success
#^Out: ['/watch?v=K_yEaIBByFo&list=UUrtZO4nmCBN4C9ySmi013oA', ...]
#Awesome! List of all url's that begin with 'watch?v=..."
#Now only if I could get the titles of the links...

contents = [text.text_content() for text in urls if text.startswith('/watch')]
#^Empty list.

#I thought this paragraph below wouldn't work,
#   but I decided to try it anyway.
texts_fail = doc.xpath('//a/[@href="watch"]')
#^XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
#^Oops, I made a syntax error there. I forgot a '/' before 'watch'.
#    But after correcting it (below), the output is the same.
texts_fail = doc.xpath('//a/[@href="/watch"]')
#^XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
texts_false = doc.xpath('//a/@href="watch"')
texts_false
#^Out: False
#^Typo again. But again, the output is still the same.
texts_false = doc.xpath('//a/@href="/watch"')
texts_false
#^Out: False

target_tag = ''.join(('//a/@class=',
                        '"yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  ',
                        'yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2"'))
texts_html = doc.xpath(target_tag)
#^Out: True
#But YouTube doesn't make attributes for link titles.
texts_tree = tree.xpath(target_tag)
#^Out: True

#I also tried this below, which I found in another stackoverflow question.
#It fails. The error is below.
doc_abs = doc.make_links_absolute(url)
#^Creates empty list, which is why the rest of this paragraph fails.
text = []
text_content = []
notText = []
hasText = []
for each in doc_abs.iter():
    if each.text:
        text.append(each.text)
        hasText.append(each)   # list of elements that has text each.text is true
    text_content.append(each.text_content()) #the text for all elements 
    if each not in hasText:
        notText.append(each)
#AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
#<ipython-input-215-38c68f560efe> in <module>()
#----> 1 for each in doc_abs.iter():
#      2     if each.text:
#      3         text.append(each.text)
#      4         hasText.append(each)   # list of elements that has text each.text is true
#      5     text_content.append(each.text_content()) #the text for all elements
#
#AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iter'
```

I'm out of ideas. Anyone want to help this python padawan? :P

-----EDIT-----

I'm a step further, thanks to `theSmallNothing`. This command gets the text elements:

```
doc.xpath('//a/text()')
```

Unfortunately, that command returns a lot of whitespace and newlines ('\n') as values. I'll probably post another question later for that issue. If I do, I'll put a link to that question here in case anyone else with the same question ends up here.

[How to use lxml to pair 'url links' with the 'names' of the links (eg. {name: link})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367543/how-to-use-lxml-to-pair-url-links-with-the-names-of-the-links-eg-name-li)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your example you want to use the text selector in your xpath query:

```
doc.xpath('//a/text()')
```

which returns the text element of all the **a** elements it can find.

To get the href and text of all the **a** elements, which I think your trying to do, you can first extract all the **a** elements, then iterate and extract the href and text individually.

```
watch_els = []

els = doc.xpath('//a')
for el in els:
    text = el.xpath("//text()")
    href = el.xpath("//@href")
    #check text and href arrays are not empty...
    if len(href) <= 0 or len(text) <= 0:
        #empty text/href, skip.
        continue

    text = text[0]
    href = href[0]
    if "/watch?" in href:
        #do something with a youtube video link...
        watch_els.append((text, href))
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! :D I thought it was going to be something simple like that. Is there a way to push this command so that it only shows the text elements of tags which have attributes beginning with 'href=/watch..."? I can't figure out lxml's regex syntax.

Comment: No probs. Its not really regex, its actually completely different and you can look it up http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/ . Though I should warn you trying to select (extract elements) on their contents (ie the start of the href attribute) is tricky, you probably want to just use the format I used above with the 'for' loop except check the start of the url (href attribute) with python's startswith string method https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: Good idea. That sounds simple, but I can't get it to work. I'm getting a lot of values for doc.xpath('//a') that are just whitespace or '\n'.

Comment: Here's what I've tried if you're curious. I'll probably post this as another question later though, cause it's a whole different issue.

`import re  
texts = doc.xpath('//a/text()')  
texts_test = []  
texts_test2 = []  
for t in texts:  
    texts_test.append(t.strip())  
    if re.findall('\S', t):  
        texts_test2.append(t)  

urls = doc.xpath('//a/@href')  
len(texts_test)  
#263  
len(texts_test2)  
#44  
len(urls)  
#109`

Comment: Yikes! Haha the newlines didn't work. Yeah, I'll definitely post this as another question later.  I might as well post what else I've tried though.

`from collections import defaultdict
links_dic_pre = dict(zip(urls, str(texts)))
links_dic = defaultdict()
for key, value in links_dic_pre.items():
    if key.startswith('https://www.youtube.com/watch'):
        links_dic[key] = value`

Comment: Haha idk what your doing, I've updated the answer to show what I mean but like you said its probably better in a different question. Oh and if your satisfied with my answer please accept it, I like rep and it means the question isn't auto deleted in a month or so.

Comment: I think there is an error in the code: in both `el.xpath` rows `//` must be removed to work as intended